# Is there a limit to the amount of client scripts that can be uploaded to a record?

Tags: netsuite

I remember reading somewhere about how for client scripts, only 10 could be loaded on a record at a time.  Does anybody know this is true.

I don't mean deployed to a record - you can deploy more than that.  But when a record is loaded, is there a limit?

The reason I ask is that in practice, Netsuite is limiting me to loading 11 client scripts (and attached scripts) at a time.  I can't load any more.  Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per NetSuite, for client-scripts

> For performance reasons, only the first 10 deployed scripts are executed

I haven't faced this yet, but I prefer using workflow or some other method rather than using client-scripts. Also deploying many client scripts can take a toll on user experience.

Check [this](https://tstdrv1395241.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_n2936246.html) out for further reading.

Comment: Can confirm this in practice.  We once reached that limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, client script on a record limited to 10. its adviced that should not be more than 10 for performance reason and code maintenance.

However, you can try using userevent script and use setScript() to attach a clientscript.